# CHECKCAST is necessary or not?

Tags: java, java-8

```
package p;

public class X {
    private int x;

    public X supp(Function<Integer, X> f){
        return f.apply( 1);
    }
}
```

And bytecode for the `supp`:

```
  public supp(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lp/X;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 24 L0
    ALOAD 1
    ICONST_1
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Integer.valueOf (I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/function/Function.apply (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    CHECKCAST p/X
    ARETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lp/X; L0 L1 0
    LOCALVARIABLE f Ljava/util/function/Function; L0 L1 1
```

And the first version of bytecode is bit quirky for me, especially `CHECKCAST p/X`.

I don't understand that. I know that there is a generic type erasure in runtime (so, in fact `f.apply(1)` returns `Object` instead of `X` whileas `supp` returns `X`. So this check casting looks like `java` (interpreter) would try to make sure that `f.apply(1)` returns `X` in fact.

But, why is it necessary? It looks like `java` doesn't trust `javac`. Basically, there is no real generic in Java- everyting based on type checking in compile time.

Comment: [Type Erasure: Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html): second point: *Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.* `supp` must return a `X`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, but please note that `f` is a an argument to the `supp`. So it must return `X`

Comment: Your cast is necessary because of the return type in the method signature `public X supp` - everything to the right doesn't matter (for the cast).

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean now.

Comment: What part is confusing? If your method was `void` then there would not be that `CHECKCAST` on the return value from the method. Note that `Function.apply` on the prior line is using `Object/Object` **because** of type erasure.

Comment: I have to ask in another way: Do you see the situation that test CHECKCAST fail?

Comment: @Gilgamesz u mean where it actually throws a ClassCastException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CHECKCAST` is necessary, because as a result of type erasure there is no information about function return type at runtime.

For example, nothing stops you from passing a raw `Function` to the `supp` method:

```
X x = new X();
Function f = o -> new Y();
x.supp(f);
```

This code compiles (with an unchecked assignment warning), but throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime.